# Row space and systems of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am seeking a more meaningful way to understand the concept of row space. I've come up with the following two interpretations, which I haven't seen anywhere else, so I'd like to check that they are correct/appropriate. The interpretations are based on the theorem that two matrices are row-equivalent if and only if they have the same row space. So:

(1) Start with $m \times n$ matrix $A$. Let $W$ be its row space. I am tempted to think of the row space of $A$ as a way of generating all row-equivalent matrices to $A$, using the following procedure: Let $w_1, \dots, w_m$ be any collection of $m$-many vectors selected from $W$ that spans $W$. Let $B$ be the matrix whose rows are the vectors $w_1, \dots, w_m$. Then $B$ is row-equivalent to $A$. So, the row space of $A$ is a way of generating all row-equivalent matrices to $A$.

(2) Building on (1), a matrix may represent the coefficients of a homogeneous system of linear equations, and row-equivalent matrices represent equivalent systems, having the same solution sets. So, the row space of matrix $A$ is a way of generating all systems of linear equations that are equivalent to $A$ as well.

Basically, are these correct interpretations of row space? If so, are there resources that build on these ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements are more or less true. However, in my opinion it is not beneficial to think of the row space in this manner. When thinking of the row space the first thought that should come to mind is its basic definition, the span of the rows of a matrix.  So it's a subspace that could look like a line or a plane or some higher-dimensional plane. That's really all there is to it.

Now you can go on and think about properties of the row space. In (1) You accurately note that matrices are row equivalent if and only if they have the same row space. But your description of the row space as "as a way of generating all row-equivalent matrices" doesn't quite make sense.  The row space is not a "method" it's just an object. If you want to think about a "way to generate  all row-equivalent matrices" you can think about "a way to generate all matrices with the same row space" instead.

The same problem occurs in (2). Saying the row space is "a way to generate all linear systems equivalent to A" doesn't make sense since you haven't actually described a process to do this.

Comment: Thank you! I think that more precisely, I was trying to say something like, "The row space represents the set of all possible row vectors that might be selected from to form a matrix that is row equivalent to $A$." Almost like...the row space is the more fundamental object and each specific row equivalent matrix is just a specific instance of a procedure such as the one I described. Does that clarify my meaning?

Comment: Yes that's right. 

There's another way you can think about it if you've gotten to the section about orthogonality. The solution set to Ax = 0 will be the "orthogonal complement" of the row space of A.  From this perspective, it is not too difficult to work out A and B will have the same solution set if and only if they have the same row space.